# finding system of linear equations in a flow picture

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure if I am reading the flow correctly. This is my first time doing linear algebra and I am not confident that I am reading the diagram properly.

Here is the pic of the questions, since I can't upload pictures yet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rodLo.png

From the picture, I found the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
   x1 +x3 - x2 = 40\\
   x1-x4 = 60\\
   x3+x4+x5 = 10\\
   x2 +x5 =30
\end{align*}

I am not sure if I am reading the flow chart properly. I would like some clarification if I am doing anything wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Where are these numbers coming from? Why is not $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10$?

Comment: Same remark as @VanBaffo. Another one $x_1+x_3-x_2=40$ not $108$ !

Comment: Anyhow, once you have written all the equations in a proper way, you will meet a problem: you have 5 unknowns and only 4 equations...

Comment: @VanBaffo Thank you I copied the wrong answers. There was another question like this in the textbook.

Comment: Ok, now it is correct. Have you already encountered the notion of rank of a matrix?

Comment: Have you noticed that (Eq. 1)-(Eq. 2) gives the same result as (Eq. 3)-(Eq. 4) ? It means you have a redundancy allowing you to suppress (any) one of these equations...